# UICollectionVIew NIL after instantiation

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView, connected as an outlet to a UICollectionView in storyboard. I have this as part of my code:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
    SetActivityIndicator()

    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)

    ProductsCollection = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

    ProductsCollection.dataSource = self // Here it says ProductsCollection is nil!
    ProductsCollection.delegate = self
```

And after the instantiation line `ProductsCollection = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)` ProductsCollection is nil. What am I doing wrong ?

Edit: I disconnected the outlet, yet I am still getting nil in the same line.

The exception:

[image: The Exception]

Comment: Why are you connecting it through storyboard if you want to reinstantiate it?

Comment: I know the connection should be deleted, but I don't think this is the cause of the problem, right ?

Comment: I have disconnected the outlet, it is still nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not creating the collection view in the storyboard then you need to delete the `weak` from the property declaration in code.

Also, variable names begin with a lowercase letter. It should be `productsCollectionView`. Make sure you update that too.

Comment: But why when I'm creating collection view in storyboard and not deleting `weak` everything works perfect?

Comment: @IvanSmetanin because the collectionView is strongly referenced by the view you are adding it to. So even though the view controller has a weak reference the view still has a strong reference. When you create it in code as weak and it is not added to the view then there are no strong references to it and so it is deallocated.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote this code in my project and everything works perfect.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var productsCollection: UICollectionView?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 80, height: 80)

        productsCollection = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

        productsCollection?.dataSource = self
        productsCollection?.delegate = self
    }

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {

}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        return UICollectionViewCell()
    }

}
```

Comment: My UIViewController already implements these interface and the functions you wrote...

Comment: @Ofri But still found nil? Everything exactly like in my answer?

Comment: Not EXACTLY. It's without the extension, but let me try yours out

Comment: I tried your code (Excluding inner functions logic) and it still finds nil

Comment: @Ofri You can try write in a such way self.ProductsCollection = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)

Comment: Still throws an exception "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

Comment: Of function "ViewDidLoad" ?

Comment: @Ofri Of ViewController

Comment: Iboutlets are weak and implicitly unwrapped so your code is not the same. It is the weak connection causing this. Also, the whole thing of creating a view in storyboard and then overwriting it is just bizarre.

Comment: It did have the "Weak" keyword. I deleted it now (Along with the outlet decleration) and trying again

Comment: Ivan - Please edit your answer and make sure it's clear that the "weak" should not be there, and I'll mark this as the correct answer :)

Comment: @Fogmeister I fixed only property name. Property was strong every time =/

Comment: @IvanSmetanin ok yes. I’ll give you that. Your code is fine. But there was no mention of what was actually causing the problem and how to fix it. So the `weak` was never removed and still remained an issue.

Comment: His answer was correct, just didn't point out that differende, that's why I asked him to edit it. Anyway, I awarded you with the correct answer